# Terraform resource github_repository_webhook requires GitHub organization to be set on the provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, webhooks, terraform-provider-aws, iaas

I am Making a CI/CD pipeline with terraform AWS. This pipeline works 100 percent perfect if I don't configure webhooks rather than goes with default option i.e AWS CodePipeline which periodically checks for changes in github.

When I configure webhooks for my pipeline to make it start automatically on every push. I am getting below error which is at the end after the code. I understand one solution that is "if I make an organization and set individual=false in my providers settings" it will work.

But I don't want to make an organization rather wants to work with individual = true. Is there any way by which I can solve this problem?

P.S: I added only those files in this question which are related to my problem. If you want me to add my whole code please request revision

Filename: Provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = var.aws_region
  version = "2.55"

}

provider "github" {
  token      = var.github_token
  individual = true
}


terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key    = "ecs_fargate/infrastructure.tfstate"
    bucket = "umartahir-terraform-buckettestus-east-1"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }

}
```

Filename: Codepipeline.tf

```
#Code Pipeline
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  name     = var.pipeline_name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.codepipeline_role.arn

  artifact_store {
    location = var.bucket_for_codepipeline
    type     = var.artifact_store_type
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = var.source_stage_owner
      provider         = var.source_stage_provider
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = var.source_stage_output_artifact_name

      configuration = {
        PollForSourceChanges = false
        OAuthToken           = var.github_token
        Owner                = var.git_hub_owner
        Repo                 = var.repo_name
        Branch               = var.branch_name
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name             = "Build"
      category         = "Build"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeBuild"
      input_artifacts  = var.source_stage_output_artifact_name
      output_artifacts = ["build_output"]
      version          = "1"

      configuration = {
        ProjectName = aws_codebuild_project.code_build_stage_pipeline.name
      }
    }
  }
}

# See this in detail later

# A shared secret between GitHub and AWS that allows AWS
# CodePipeline to authenticate the request came from GitHub.
# Would probably be better to pull this from the environment
# or something like SSM Parameter Store.

locals {
  webhook_secret = "super-secret"
}

resource "aws_codepipeline_webhook" "github_hook" {
  name            = var.github_hook_name
  authentication  = "GITHUB_HMAC"
  target_action   = "Source"
  target_pipeline = aws_codepipeline.codepipeline.name


  authentication_configuration {
    secret_token = "${local.webhook_secret}"
  }

  filter {
    json_path    = "$.ref"
    match_equals = "refs/heads/{Branch}" #see this later
  }
}

# # See this in detail later
# # Wire the CodePipeline webhook into a GitHub repository.
resource "github_repository_webhook" "web_hook_github" {
  repository = var.repo_name
  configuration {
    url          = aws_codepipeline_webhook.github_hook.url
    content_type = "json"
    insecure_ssl = true
    secret       = local.webhook_secret
  }
  events = ["push"]
}
```

Logs:

```
aws_iam_role.example: Creating...
aws_iam_role.codepipeline_role: Creating...
aws_iam_role.codepipeline_role: Creation complete after 3s [id=test-role]
aws_iam_role_policy.codepipeline_policy: Creating...
aws_iam_role.example: Creation complete after 3s [id=example]
aws_iam_role_policy.example: Creating...
aws_codebuild_project.code_build_stage_pipeline: Creating...
aws_iam_role_policy.example: Creation complete after 4s [id=example:terraform-20200414180138343300000001]
aws_iam_role_policy.codepipeline_policy: Creation complete after 4s [id=test-role:codepipeline_policy]
aws_codebuild_project.code_build_stage_pipeline: Creation complete after 9s [id=arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-1:359761372359:project/umartahir-terraform-codebuild]
aws_codepipeline.codepipeline: Creating...
aws_codepipeline.codepipeline: Creation complete after 7s [id=umar-tahir-terraform-codepipeline]
aws_codepipeline_webhook.github_hook: Creating...
aws_codepipeline_webhook.github_hook: Creation complete after 4s [id=arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:359761372359:webhook:webhook-github-codepipeline]
github_repository_webhook.web_hook_github: Creating...


Error: This resource requires GitHub organization to be set on the provider.
  on codepipeline.tf line 87, in resource "github_repository_webhook" "web_hook_github":
  87: resource "github_repository_webhook" "web_hook_github"
```

Answer (score 1):

seems to be an existing issue.
Here is a link to the thread - https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-github/issues/45